# Adobe Illustrator Line Pattern Distortion Fold

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, illustrator-effects

[image]
Does anyone know how to create an effect like this in Illustrator? I need to understand how to create this angled wave/fold effect in a line pattern from scratch so that I can create my own styled one for a logo purpose Please help!

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems you may have forgotten an image.

Comment: Thanks Scott, fixed it!

Answer (score 4):

To make it like your example draw an array of rectangles:
Rotate group 45 degrees then use Object>Envelope Distort>Make With Mesh(Alt+Ctrl+M) with 1 row and 7 columns.
Select the anchorpoints to the right with direct selection tool(A) and move them to desired position, see images below. 
Then you can rotate the group back 45 degrees.
[image]
Select anchorpoints marked with red circles.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Mikael, thank you so much for the response,this makes perfect sense but when I get to evelope distort it doesn't quite work like yours, I wish that I could attach an image her, but when I go to use the envelope distort it seems to effect the edges differently and doesn't quite give the same fold. Would you be open to making a short video or screen capture of yourself doing it so I can better understand? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Tom! First I just want to make sure you selected all the anchor points? I made some changes in the pictures to show what I mean. Depending on the shape you are doing you might experiment with direction and how far you move the anchorpoints. You can also try with other amount of columns, 3-5-7-9...etc.

Comment: This approach is wonderful, and makes for an easy smooth waving flag with all kinds of lovely details - *really* ***great*** technique, @MikaelCarlsson!

Comment: Fantastic Mikael, I will experiment a bit, I did select the anchor points that you have highlighted, (thank you so much for doing that) but it may be the case of my line length and needing to mess with coloumns, will report back today! Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Mikael, I wish i could upload a photograph here, would you be willing to send an email to my personal email so i can show you the difficulty I am having no matter how many columns I choose? I really want to master this for a client logo so I don't have to worry about copyright issues of that original shape since the designer put some really great work together and id like to make one my own. My email is tfrancesconi15@gmail.com if you would be ok with continuing this so I can send you screen shots.

Comment: @MikaelCarlsson I actually was able to edit my original post to show the screen shots of my progress and what the result I keep getting is, and this is generally happening even with different number of rows and distances of pulling and pushing the mesh, it really effects the edges and never looks as smooth as your example

Comment: Try change the Fidelity in Object > Envelope Distort > Envelope Options. It could be what cause problem. My is set to 50.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

**The Process Is Quite Easy : Just Repetitive**

Step 1 : Draw a rectangle via `Rectangle Tool`
[image]

Step 2 : Add `Four Random Points` as below image via `Pen Tool`[image]

Step 3 : Select points and use allign [image] to allign them vertically
[image]

Step 4 : Select last 4 anchor points and move them `Upwards`
[image]

Step 5 : Select middle points and drag that `circular dot`[image]

Step 7 : Now just keep repeting it; duplicate object move them down; move middle points by going into isolation mode and that's it ; you'll get the above effect
[image]

Comment: Go with @Mikael Carlsson answers; It's quite unique and handy :)

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do it is:

Making the first and the last shape.

Now we can use the blend tool and adjust the steps.

More additional information on how to make the shape.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Leo, I guess my question is more in the best way to make the original shape from scratch, other than just completely pen tooling it, but this is super helpful once I get there!

Comment: Amazing thank you so much!